# Best way for user to create category tree

Tags: usability, interaction-design, design-patterns, categorization, product-design

Our clients need to create a shop structure with many categories and subcategories, and our current system is not very easy for them.

I thought the best way would be just a blank text area - creating categories by writing it's name and pressing enter, and subcategories by pressing tab and writing name.

[image: Text area category creation]

It's probably the quickest, but on the other hand, I think it might not be obvious enough and also you can't set up other attributes of the category.

**What would be the best practice to enable users to quickly create a whole set of categories?**

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against simply providing a text area as:

- It's **not obvious to the user what structure you require**.
- Introduces the opportunity for them to enter **invalid syntax**.

However, the following methods utilised by Wordpress will be more UX friendly, and allow you to enter other attributes:

1. **Drag-and-drop**
2. **Select parent from a list**

---

### Drag-and-Drop

Instead, the Wordpress drag-and-drop *Menu Structure* system works well.

[image: Wordpress Menu Structure]

It's a drag-and-drop system which allows the user to visually re-arrange the hierarchy.

If implementing Drag-and-drop, you'll want to follow [Nielsen's advice](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-application-design-mistakes/):

> Drag-and-drop designs are often the worst offenders when **it's not apparent that something can be dragged** or where something can be dropped. (Or what will happen if you do drag or drop.)
>
> Common symptoms of the lack of perceived affordances are:
>
> - Users say, "What do I do here?"
> - Users don't go near a feature that would help them.
> - A profusion of screen text tries to overcome these two problems.

---

### Select parent from a list

Alternatively, Wordpress also has another method: **Select a parent from a drop-down list**.

[image: Select parent from drop-down]

This is:

- Easier to implement.
- Doesn't require you to make affordances of draggability.
- *But* the hierarchy is less visually obvious.